# Como hacer un procedimiento almacenado para que me arroje todos los datos de los usuarios que tengan roles y los que no tengan roles asignados

Tags: oracle-11g, plsql

por favor alguien me puede ayudar con el siguiente problema,el procedimiento que tengo solo me arroja los nombres de los usuarios que solo tienen roles, pero yo quiero que arroje todos los usuarios que tengan roles y los que no tengan roles asignado.

estas son las 3 tablas

```
usuariosroles |usuarios| roles
```

este es mi procedimiento

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Consultar ( l_nombre usuarios.nombre%type)                        
AS
     CURSOR l_cursor IS 
  SELECT usuarios.IDUSUARIOS,
      usuariosroles.idusuarios,
      roles.idrol,
      usuariosroles.idrol,
      roles.nombre,
      usuarios.nombre
        FROM usuarios
             left JOIN usuariosroles ON usuarios.IDUSUARIOS=usuariosroles.IDUSUARIOS
             left JOIN roles
                ON usuariosroles.idrol=roles.idrol
                WHERE usuarios.nombre=l_nombre;
                x1 NUMBER;
                x2 NUMBER;
                x3 NUMBER;
                x4 NUMBER;
                x5 VARCHAR(400);
                x6 VARCHAR(400);
BEGIN
   OPEN l_cursor; 
    FETCH l_cursor INTO x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6;   
 if l_cursor%found then
dbms_output.put_line(x5||', '||x6);  
  else 
  dbms_output.put_line('dato no encontrado '); 
  END if;
  CLOSE  l_cursor;
END Consultar;
```